# VIM - Add a space before left parens if a space doesn't exist before

Tags: vim

What would the quickest way for me to insert a single space before a left parentheses if there is not one there yet?

Examples:

```
hello() -> hello ()
world () -> world ()
hello(world ()) -> hello (world ())
```

It's required for a style guide, I'm supposed to follow for class, and I just don't do it automatically, so how can I have vim do this for me.

Comment: check http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Search_and_replace. for your case `:%s/^\s(/\s(/g`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a mapping:

```
function! SpaceBeforeLeftParen()
    :silent! s/\v \(/(/g
    :silent! s/\v\(/ (/g
endfunction
nnoremap c( :call SpaceBeforeLeftParen()<CR>
```

Just hit <kbd>c</kbd><kbd>(</kbd> on a line where you want the space to be added. Or you can directly call the function: `:call SpaceBeforeLeftParen()`

--

Some other approaches for the substitution:

- `s/\(\s\+\)\@<!(/ (/`
- `s/\v([^ ])(\()/\1 (/g`

--

**Possibly the best complete answer**, derived from @Marth's comment would be:

```
function! SpaceBeforeLeftParen()
  :silent! %s/\(\s\+\)\@<!(/ (/
endfunction
```

...which will handle the whole file in one shot. Invoke with `:call SpaceBeforeLeftParen()`

Comment: This will add a space before a `(` even if there already was one. Also I'm guessing the `verbose mode` (`\v`) is a reflex, but it's kind of counter-productive here :).

Comment: What's `\v` I don't see that on the vim wiki?

Comment: @HSchmale it's "very magic mode" which basically lets you use perl-style regex. See here for more info: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Simplifying_regular_expressions_using_magic_and_no-magic

Comment: You could do this in one go using a negative look-behind with `:%s/\(\s\+\)\@<!(/ (/`.

Comment: @Marth nice one. I included yours along with another one that I came up with in my answer